# Patent us20110086189

Tags: prior-art, defensive-publications, us20110086189

This patent seems to describe or use elements of an Invention I patented in Australia, USA UK etc in the late 1970s and has subsequently been used and or published in uniaxial, triaxial sesquiaxial and septaxial forms.  These patents expired long ago.  The product has been used for breakwaters and coastal and lakeshore erosion control, spillways and SUDS driveways, and for retaining walls stacked on end and on sides.

Photos, design manuals and basic design software are available on request from chrisbrown.seabees@gmail.com

Was this prior Art disclosed in the patent application? What is the inventive step that allows the granting of some parts of this patent?

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Brown,

I spend a fair amount of time on the water and appreciate your contributions.

To answer part of your question, the examiner cited your patent 4,172,680 as relevant art.  This reference appears to have been discovered during the Examiner's search. It appears, however, that this application issued on a first office action allowance.

Answer (score 1):

You could have provided your Australian patent number, or any other equivalent. In other effort, you may look at the US PAIR to check if your patent was considered in the prosecution of US 2011 00086189. Hope this helps.